# Quick Smoke for Ink Drop, but smoke is showing squares

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to use "Quick Smoke"-effect to create an Ink Drop scene.

I've been following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpYI6T4ILEo and everything looks great except that my ball of smoke is showing some squares inside of it.

See image below. Any tips or suspicions on what can be wrong is greatly appreciated.

(MacBook M1 Max, Blender 3.1.0 Beta, also tested in Blender 3.0.1 and same result)

Here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6vBswevOWCDAmK-ExnU7bsIDeanBbqq/view?usp=sharing

[image: Blender Drop Ink – My view and settings]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: My bad. File is included now.